# SVN permission problem on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, permissions, svn

In tortoisesvn i get the error

```
Can't create directory 'C:\dev\repo\subfolder\db\transactions\49-1g.txn': ...
```

I used robocopy (i cant remember if i used /copyall) to copy the files onto an external drive then i copied it back after a format. Now ATM i cannot commit. How do i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem was missing folders (perhaps not copying empty folders). I created a repo then copy/pasted the files into it. It then worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The files have to be in **exactly** the same directory as before for TortoiseSVN to work properly.

Comment: they are. Actually what is funny is c:\dev is actually a junction point to my other partition so all of my os will have c:\ pointing to the exact same folder. So in both cases (c: and e:) the folders are in the same directory as before.